# Huffman Coding. Text as binary.

Tags: c#, math

I need to save encoded text to binary file. ".bin" with BinaryWriter and read it with BinaryReader.

I using Huffman Coding to encode text and characters and then i make it more readable by string builder and in the end I have that:

```
A:1111;l:1011;a:00; :01;m:1010;k:100;o:1110;t:1100;e:11010;.:11011;
111110110001101000011001110110000010001100111011000110100001111110111101011011
```

when I save it to binary file this way:

```
(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)))
            foreach (var bit in binaryString)
                writer.Write(bit);
```

And opening the .bin file via notepad it shows full text. Encoded. I need to make it not readable. For e.q. if you open .exe in olds systems via notepad it shows random characters like [, [] ##$# $# #%$^$ ^&% or something like that.

How I can do it?

I need also to read that binary file and decode it. 
Reading:

```
var bits = new List<byte>();
        int position = 0,
            length;
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            length = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
            while (position < length)
            {
                bits.Add(reader.ReadByte());
                position++;
            }
        }
```

And decoding:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nDekodujemy!\n");
        int lineFeed = 0x0a,
            semicolon = 0x3b,
            colon = 0x3a;


        List<byte> structBits = new List<byte>();
        List <byte> textBits = new List<byte>();

        bool isStructBits = true;
        foreach(var bit in bits)
        {
            if (bit == lineFeed)
            {
                isStructBits = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (isStructBits)
                structBits.Add(bit);
            else
                textBits.Add(bit);
        }

        Console.Write("Zdekodowana struktura: ");
        foreach (var bit in structBits)
            Console.Write((char)bit);
        Console.Write("\nZakodowany tekst: ");
        foreach (var bit in textBits)
            Console.Write((char)bit);

        var charactersMap = new Dictionary<char, string>();

        Console.WriteLine("\nDekodowanie struktury!");
        {
            bool isKey = true, isValue = false;
            char key = ' ';
            string value = "";
            foreach (var bit in structBits)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", key);
                if (isKey)
                {
                    if (!charactersMap.ContainsKey((char)bit))
                    {
                        key = (char)bit;
                        isKey = false;
                    }
                }
                if (bit == colon)
                {
                    isValue = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if (bit == semicolon)
                {
                    isValue = false;
                    isKey = true;
                    charactersMap.Add(key, value);
                    value = "";

                }
                if (isValue)
                {
                    value += (char)bit;
                }

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nKluczy: {0}\nZdekodowane klucze:", charactersMap.Count);
        foreach (var key in charactersMap.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", key, charactersMap[key]);


        Console.WriteLine("\nDekodowanie tekstu!");
        string decodedText = "";
        string temp = "";
        foreach (var bit in textBits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bit: {0}", (char)bit);
            Console.WriteLine("Temp: {0}", temp);
            temp += (char)bit;

            foreach (var key in charactersMap.Keys)
                if (charactersMap[key] == temp)
                {
                    decodedText += key;
                    temp = "";
                    break;
                }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nZdekodowano: {0}", decodedText);
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: So you question is _"I need to make it not readable"_? What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: I need to save it as bits. Not characters.

Comment: So, you want to encrypt the binary file text?

Comment: Bits form bytes, and when you open a file in a text editor, it tries its best to show characters that correspond to those bytes' values.

Comment: Right. So what to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand what you are trying to do, you are writing each bit of encoded message as a whole byte but you want to write them as bits. So, you should pack this bits in bytes before write them in file. In place where you build your **binaryString** you should merge each 8 bits in one single byte (using bit operations).

Comment: How to encode text as bits? That way you say.But then how to find that A:111? If 'A' will be 8 bits ':' 8 bit and "111" will be? How to decode that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first part of data in file is a dictionary (codebook) for Huffman algorithm. If so, then you should store it in some binary format that would be easy to unpack. You can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code#Encoding_the_codebook
The only thing is that you must be able to predict exact number of bits used for dictionary in order to be able read it unambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `binaryString` is of type `string` you can use a method like the following to convert it to a collection of `byte`s:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> AsHuffmanCode(this string source)
{
    const int BitsPerByte = 8;
    const int LastBit = 7;
    byte huffmanByte = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < source.Length; index++)
    {
        var bit = source[index] == '0' ? 0 : 1;
        var bitPosition = index % BitsPerByte;

        huffmanByte |= (byte)(bit << bitPosition);

        if (bitPosition == LastBit)
        {
            yield return huffmanByte;
            huffmanByte = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)))
{
    foreach (var huffmanByte in binaryString.AsHuffmanCode())
        writer.Write(huffmanByte);
}
```

See [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gYFGy4) for a running version.

The basic idea is to read the string `char` by `char`, accumulate the bit values of the characters and return that accumulated value after every 8th character. Accumulation happens by OR'ing the bit values, each bit-shifted depending on its position in the string.

Decoding a `byte` to a `string` should be straight forward. Just do the inverse operation.

Be aware that this method does no error checking whatsoever.